# How to resort my id in wordpress?

Tags: sort

When i select id from my wordpress with command `select id from wp_posts;`,the output is such as following:

```
| 1382 |
| 1384 |
| 1386 |
| 1388 |
| 1392 |
| 1396 |
| 1399 |
| 1401 |
| 1403 |
| 1406 |
+------+
```

I want to set my id to be continuous such as

```
| 1382 |
| 1383 |
| 1384 |
| 1385 |
+------+
```

The following three lines of mysql make the id continuous.

```
ALTER TABLE `wp_posts` DROP `ID`;
OPTIMIZE TABLE `wp_posts`;
ALTER TABLE `wp_posts` ADD `ID` BIGINT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY FIRST;
```

But i lost every article's category attribution in the wordpress.
How to fix it ?

Comment: You've destroyed the relationships not only between posts and categories, but between posts and tags, custom taxonomies, post meta including thumbnail images, custom post meta... I am sure there is more. And I doubt you remember the attributions enough to rebuild from memory. Why would you do this? And, more importantly, why would you do it without bothering to understand how the WordPress tables relate to one another?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what your intension is in doing this, but there are a couple of very important things to consider here

- Revisions, drafts, menus, custom post type and attachments are saved in the `wp_posts` table, not only `post` post type posts, so you will never have two posts having ID's which difference is `1`
- Not all postdata is saved in the `wp_posts` table. Wordpress uses the `wp_postmeta` table to save information about attachments belonging to posts, save custom fields, save info about templates (for `page` post type) etc. There is also the `wp_term_relationships` table which is used to establish a relationship between posts and its terms assigned to them. In all cases, Wordpress uses the post ID to establish relationships between items in the `wp_posts` and these two other db tables. Changing post ID's in `wp_posts` breaks all these relationships
- MYSQL databases has a huge maximum ID integer, which you will in all probabilty never fill. For a full break up on this, please see [this post on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11264482/1908141)

To conclude, if you don't have a back up of your database, you are in all probabilty stuffed. As Wordpress uses post ID's to establish relationships, and you have changed the post ID's, the only reliable method to do re-establish relationships will be to do this manually. I cannot see any other reliable method doing this

If you really need to change post ID's, the best option will be to use a function like [`wp_update_post`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_update_post)and writing a wrapper function to do what you need. This is quite expensive operations, so you will probably time out or exhaust memory on a huge database, so you will need to break your operation up into manageable chunks and run the function a couple of times.